# A Word that means both furniture and appliances?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that means both furniture and appliances ?

*Also optionally includes lawnmower, rakes, vacuums, brooms, cabinets, coat racks, etc.*

An example would be...”Everyone is entitled to get for free any one brand new furnipliance for each enrollment"

Comment: Unless you're talking about something like [*rummage*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rummage#h2) ("a confused miscellaneous collection"), I can think of no word that applies to both of those types of items. Plus, that word would include many other things too.

Comment: 'Household goods' might do it. Or 'home contents'. Or even just 'stuff'.

Comment: Insurance companies call them contents as far as I know. You can insure home and contents (at least where I'm from), they're separate things.

Comment: Hi Eagers, welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are **strict rules** for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you want to _exclude_ smaller items and personal items like books, clothing, musical instruments (other than pianos and other large keyboard instruments), jewellery and children's toys?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at literature around furnished apartments, it seems that they try to skirt around the lack of a fully generic word for the stuff that comes with the apartment. So it seems that there just isn't a word that means exactly “furniture and appliances”, let alone a word that works out of context. “Furniture and appliances” is a common juxtaposition. “Amenities” sometimes comes up, but it's too general since it can also include a lot of other things such as services, and conversely it only works if the things are provided with the house. “***Items***” also comes up, and I think it works well if the context makes it clear what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be recognised by your target audience, but **chattels**

https://www.morrishsolicitors.com/resources/property/buying-a-house-chattels-fixtures-and-stripped-out-houses/

> Chattels are items of personal property, ie. assets that are clearly identifiable and movable. Fixtures have been installed in or fixed to the property, therefore becoming part of the building.